# How to find the x, y and z rotational angles for the given directional vector and up vector?

Tags: c#, vector, matrix, xna, transformation

I have a superclass object which represents a model in a scene.  This object contains a 3D vector, `position` for its location and three variables `x`, `y` and `z` to describe its rotation around those axes.  Its transformation matrix is calculated as follows:

```
Matrix.CreateRotationX(x) *
Matrix.CreateRotationY(y) *
Matrix.CreateRotationZ(z) *
Matrix.CreateTranslation(position)
```

This is all working fine, except in some circumstances I need to calculate the values for `x`, `y` and `z` based on a normalised directional vector and an up vector.  How can I do this?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're asking, but if you want to know how to normalise a vector you use Vector3.Normalize()

Comment: Just to confirm: Are you asking, for a given vector, how do you determine the equivalent rotation around the three axes?

Comment: @lzcd Yes, for a given vector, I want the rotation for all three axes in the `x`, `y`, and `z` variables so that I can later calculate rotational matrices using the `CreateRotation...` methods of the `Matrix` class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert the matrix to a quaternion:

`Quaternion q = Quaternion.CreateFromRotationMatrix(matrix);`

then copy and paste [the last method found on this page](http://www.xnawiki.com/index.php?title=Vector_Math) and run your quaternion through it.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know how to do the math myself but wouldn't Matrix.CreateLookAt satisfy your needs?

```
Matrix.CreateLookAt(new Vector3(0, 0, 0), new Vector3(x, y, z), yourUpVector) 
* Matrix.CreateTranslation(position);
```

Comment: It would except at the moment the superclass has the `x`, `y` and `z` components stored separately instead of using a `Matrix`.

Answer (score 0):

Same as ClassicThunder's answer (with the same limitation that it gives you the matrix you want, rather than the angles), except it's a bit nicer than messing with `CreateLookAt` (which is really for making a view matrix).

```
Matrix.CreateWorld(position, direction, up);
```

([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb975261.aspx))

IMO, you should probably shouldn't be using or storing the Euler rotation of an object anyway. ([see also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/832805/euler-angles-vs-quaternions-problems-caused-by-the-tension-between-internal-s))